# Changing qt5 tab names dynamically

Tags: c++, qt5, qtabwidget, qplaintextedit

Say I have a tabwidget in my ui file
this is how im adding tabs right now:

```
QPlainTextEdit *tab = new QPlaintextEdit;
int index = ui->tabWidget->addTab(tab, "changeme");
```

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to change the name of the tab on the go, 
for example when subclassing QPLainTextEdit in a class and connecting a signal to it when the text changes then i'd like to add a little star to the tab to indicate that the file has been modified, is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QTabWidet::setTabText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setTabText) does what you want.

E.g:

```
ui->tabWidget->setTabText(index, "new text");
```